# How to set content of SWT Text element from an instance of a class that is called by an Eclipse command?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-pde

I implemented an Eclipse view by extending `ViewPart`. In this particular view, I have also implemented a text input field `Text` and a few buttons which execute a particular Eclipse command.

For example:

```
IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService) PlatformUI
                                .getWorkbench().getService(
                                        IHandlerService.class);
handlerService.executeCommand("com.company.commandxyz", null);
```

This command calls a handler which then invokes a service to hook into the DSF extensions. To be specific, I have implemented a custom `CommandFactory` by extending `CommandFactory_6_8`. This allows me to queue commands to GDB and then get the result back. However, I want to set the response in the Text field which is located located in the View where the `com.example.commandxyz` was invoked.

Unfortunately, I cannot pass any reference to this implementation of the DSF extension. I tried the following code to get the Eclipse view in order to subsequently set the text (which is a property of this view):

```
IViewPart vp = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("com.example.myview");
```

However, I receive the following exception upon calling:

```
Exception in thread "MI RX Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any idea how I can access the UI thread to retrieve the property of the view in order to set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PlatformUI` code you mention must run in the UI thread.

Use `Display.asyncExec` or `Display.syncExec` to execute code in the UI thread from some other thread.

With Java 8 use:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() -> { ... code to run in UI thread });
```

With earlier versions of Java use:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
     ... code to run in UI thread
  }
});
```

`asyncExec` runs the UI code asynchronously the next time the UI is ready to run code. `syncExec` runs synchronously blocking the current thread until the UI runs the code.

Comment: you're are a hero.  How in the world could i miss this. I already had it like you told me, but I only put the call of the method (from my View) into run(). Thanks a lot.